# Toggle Elements on Page refresh on click using local storage javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing the following problem:

I want to start the page with "#Before" and "#After" hidden.
- When I click on the button "Go Back", "#Before" should be shown.
- When I click on the button "Go Forward", "#After" should be shown.

But when I am clicking to show only one of the elements, and then I refresh the page. After refresh the other element is also shown. So I am seeing the two elements although I clicked only on one button.

How can I modify this code to let it work when I only want to toggle and save one of the two Elements, or when I also want to toggle both of them.

I searched a lot in the last days and found nothing.
I would be very thankful and you would save my day!

**Link to the code on jsfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/bisch_basch/6orxn6kq/10/

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='main.js'></script>
<body>
<div class="menu" id="myHeader">
    <a style="float:left" href="#">Menu</a>
    <a id="Before" href="#"> Back </a>
    <a id="Current" href="#"> Current </a>
    <a id="After" href="#"> After </a>
</div>
<button id="Button1"> Go Back </button>
<button id="Button2"> Go Forward </button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#Before").css('display','none');

$("#After").css('display','none');

$("#Button1").click(function(){
    $("#Before").toggle(); 

    var isVisible = $("#Before").is(":visible"); 
    localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
});
    var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
    $("#Before").toggle(isVisible);

$("#Button2").click(function(){
    $("#After").toggle(); 

    var isVisible = $("#After").is(":visible"); 
    localStorage.setItem('visible', isVisible);
});
    var isVisible = localStorage.getItem('visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
    $("#After").toggle(isVisible);

});
```

Comment: Just a clarification about the expected behaviour: if you first click on 'Go back' and then 'Go forward', should both #back and #after become visible?

Comment: Yes they should become visible. The problem is when i click only on Go back and #back becomes visible, then i refresh the page. After that  #after would be also with #back visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
$(function() {
  var isVisible;
  $("#After, #Before").toggle(false);

  if (localStorage.getItem('before_visible') != null) {
    isVisible = localStorage.getItem('before_visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
    $("#Before").toggle(isVisible);
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem('after_visible') != null) {
    isVisible = localStorage.getItem('after_visible') === 'false' ? false : true;
    $("#After").toggle(isVisible);
  }

  $("#Button1").click(function(){
      $("#Before").toggle();
      localStorage.setItem('before_visible', $("#Before").is(":visible"));
  });

  $("#Button2").click(function(){
      $("#After").toggle();
      localStorage.setItem('after_visible', $("#After").is(":visible"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6orxn6kq/19/)

Actually, you were just storing the state of the #After and #Before elements in a single `localstorage` key. Both referenced to the same key `visible`. So, even if one link, say 'Go Back', modified the key (intending to set the visibility to `true` for the #Before element), the same key was checked to determine the visibility of #After. As a result, #After too became visible, as it found the `visible` key in `localstorage` to be true.

What you needed to do was to separately store the visibility states for #After and #Before.